# Chained html number selects

Tags: javascript, html

Being very new to javascript, I have two html Number selects including years and I want to chain the 2nd select with the 1st one in a way that when I choose a year in first select(while the second select has no options at first), the second select should include years starting from the chosen number till the current year.

My sample HTML Code:

```
<select id="1st select" onchange="generate_selectNumbers()">
<option value="choose" selected>choose a year</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
</select
<select id="2nd select">
</select>
```

My javascript code:

```
<script>
function generate_selectNumbers(){ 
var a = document.getElementById("1st select");
var b = document.getElementById("2nd select");
var i = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getFullYear();
for (i , i <= n, i++){
    b.options[b.options.length]= new Option('i', 'i');
    }
}
</script>
```

Whenever I choose a year from the 1st select, nothing just happens to the second one and stays empty. I appreciate your correcting my js code or provide new code if mine is completely wrong. or should I use ajax for second select to refresh automatically with new options?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed your code a bit and it seem to work. Here is the working .html file.
I'd also recommend you to use more verbose variables names.

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMfL9/4/)

EDIT: updated to clear second select options before inserting new ones.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function generate_selectNumbers()
         { 
           var a = document.getElementById("selOne");
           var b = document.getElementById("selTwo");

           // clear options in second select
           for (var option in b) {
               b.remove(option);
           }

           var i = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
           var d = new Date();
           var n = d.getFullYear();
           for (i; i <= n; i++){
               b.options[b.options.length]= new Option(i, i);
           }
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <select id="selOne" onchange="generate_selectNumbers()">
         <option value="choose" selected>choose a year</option>
         <option value="2000">2000</option>
         <option value="2001">2001</option>
         <option value="2002">2002</option>
      </select>
      <select id="selTwo">
      </select>
   </body>
</html>
```